# Send current URL to email using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

Why is it that `console.log(location.href);` on https://www.amazon.com displays the correct URL in the console but when attempting to send a URL to email client using a JavaScript bookmarklet it fails to get the URL from  https://www.amazon.com?

Here is the code for the JavaScript bookmarklet that works on just about every site except amazon.com.
`javascript:location.href=%27mailto:?SUBJECT=%27+document.title+%27&BODY=%27+escape(location.href);`

NOTE: I've also tried `window.location.href` to no avail.

I've also tried this variation:
`javascript:location.href='mailto:?SUBJECT='+document.title+'&BODY='+escape(location.href);`

(Tested in Google Chrome Version 64.0.3282.140)

Comment: it works for me

Comment: Works for me as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Amazon.com's title exceeds the recommended email subject line length of 78 characters as per [RFC2322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822).

Their title is currently 84 character.
*"Amazon.com: Online Shopping for Electronics, Apparel, Computers, Books, DVDs & more"*

Interestingly enough, Outlook 2016 was only including the first 78 characters of `document.tile` and the body of the email did not include the URL from `location.href`.

After using the `slice(0, 77)` method on `document.title` the URL is now being included in the body of the email.

Here is the updated bookmarklet.

```
javascript:location.href='mailto:?SUBJECT='+document.title.slice(0, 77)+'&BODY='+escape(location.href);
```